# Mathematical Calculation on Image columns C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

How can I do mathematical calculation on column of an Image one at a time and tabulate the result for an Histogram ?

[image: 1]

8 bpp indexed. I want to calculate the width of white region from black region on every column of this image and tabulate it.

What would be the efficient method to do that ?

so far the code:

```
public static double[] fwhm(Bitmap i1)
        {
            double[] TabFWHM = new double[i1.Width];

            try
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, i1.Width, i1.Height);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                i1.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, i1.PixelFormat);
                //For every Row calculate the fwhm
                unsafe
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < i1.Width; i++)
                    {
                        // Calculate total of Image; Total[ImageData[img]];

                        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * i1.Height;
                        double[] TotalValues = new double[bytes];

                        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, TotalValues, 0, bytes);

                        // Exception shown here:

                        TabFWHM[i] = fwhmCol.ColFWHM(TotalValues);

                        // Copy the values back to the bitmap
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(TotalValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
                    }
                }//end unsafe

                i1.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                i1.Dispose();                    
            }//end try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
            return TabFWHM;
        }//end function
```

Problem:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874447/get-the-percentage-usage-of-every-colour-in-an-image

Comment: I have tried something similar, and it threw an exception for memory violation. I just want to get the values for every column and do some calculation on it.

Comment: Try something along these lines to get around your exception... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482381/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-accessviolationexception-occurred